# How to write a scope for rails (using has_scope) that finds orders that has a created_at date between two given dates(start_date & end_date)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a current scope that isn't working.

But does explain what I'm trying to achieve.

```
  scope :range, -> (start_date, end_date) { where("orders.created_at BETWEEN (?) AND (?)", start_date.to_date, end_date.to_date)}
```

I'm looking for a way to get all orders between two given dates.

I'm supplying the params correctly.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/reports/organisations/1/sales-reports?range[start_date]=2020-12-27&range[end_date]=2020-12-28
```

Any assistance with a scope that works for my use case would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add a little bit of context here. I saw your answer mentioning the use of `has_scope` but its not written in here. Also, you should try to say what you were getting instead of the expected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am thinking about is the criteria, where you are using `orders.created_at` instead of just `created_at` to scope.

Also, this makes ActiveRecord responsible of writing the SQL instead of yourself.

```
scope :range, ->(start_date, end_date) { where(created_at: start_date.to_date..end_date.to_date) }
```

As aside, I would try to pass `start_date` and `end_date` as Dates, because you are saying they are dates, not string representations of dates.

Comment: Thanks this is a lot more concise and readable

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that as I'm using has_scope gem.

all I needed was a the using the 'using' option.

```
has_scope :range, using: %i[start_date end_date], type: :hash
```